Selenium webdriver get "Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS."
I've been working with selenium and chromedriver on RHEL. I run this code to use selenium and chromedriver on with proxy
chrome_options = Options()
log_path = 'chromedriver.log'
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": "/data/code/", 
    "download.prompt_for_download": False, 
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-path={}'.format(log_path))
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://proxy:port')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Tentukan jalur ke ChromeDriver
chrome_driver_path = "/data/code/chromedriver"

# Inisialisasi service ChromeDriver
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
service.start()

# Buat instance driver Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(f"https://cfs.ojk.go.id/cfs/")

and get output like this
Message: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>

i try to curl https://cfs.ojk.go.id/cfs/ and it works after i set the proxy, but i can't use selenium to crawl any data.
in addition, i've check my /etc/hosts file and it contain the correct localhost ip address
i also try to remove the localhost ip address.
I would really appreciate any help from you!!
